# Total values of input field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the total value of all input fields

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++) { echo '

    <div class="form-group-sm" id="div_add_calc_aantal['.$j.']">
      <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control" id="add_calc_aantal['.$j.']" name="add_calc_aantal" value="" onchange="validate_edit(this, '.$j.')">
    </div>';

}
```

And place the total of these fields in

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_calc_totaal_aant" name="add_calc_totaal_aant" value="">
```

The script below is not responding / working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculatie(selectVeld, nr)
{
    // Absoluut aantal
    var i, totaal = 0;
    var elems = document.getElementById('add_calc_aantal['+nr+']').value;
    var l = elems.length;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        totaal += parseFloat(elems[i].value) || 0;
    }
        document.getElementById('add_calc_totaal_aant').value = totaal.toFixed( 0 );
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Strange code. You get a `div` DOM element, then try to access a `value` property and think you get the `input` DOM nodes inside the `div`? That's not how it works. You have to get those nodes themselves. Please have a look at your `elems` variable's actual content.

Comment: @Mörre the ids are of the input elements. The div ids have `div_` in front of them. @Muiter I recommend adding php tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Slai Confusing, okay... but he only gets a single one and still treats it as if it's an array. Very strange, what was the idea... it's kind of obvious that this doesn't do anything useful?

Comment: I don't see that he called this function `calculatie()` at all..

Answer (score 0):

Add class `.add_calc_aantal` to your loop

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++) { echo '

    <div class="form-group-sm" id="div_add_calc_aantal['.$j.']">
      <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control add_calc_aantal" id="add_calc_aantal['.$j.']" name="add_calc_aantal" value="" onchange="validate_edit(this, '.$j.')">
    </div>';
    // ---------------------------------------------------------^
}
```

Then check the sample below

```js
function calculatie() {
  // Absoluut aantal
  var totaal = 0;
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.add_calc_aantal'); // query new added class
  [].forEach.call(elems, function(e) {
    totaal += parseFloat(e.value) || 0;
  })
  document.getElementById('add_calc_totaal_aant').value = totaal.toFixed(0);
}
calculatie();
```

```html
<!-- this html was added for demo purpose, actually its generated by your server -->
<div class="form-group-sm" id="div_add_calc_aantal[1]">
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control add_calc_aantal" name="add_calc_aantal" value="34" onchange="validate_edit(this, 1)">
</div>

<div class="form-group-sm" id="div_add_calc_aantal[2]">
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control add_calc_aantal" name="add_calc_aantal" value="45" onchange="validate_edit(this, 2)">
</div>

<div class="form-group-sm" id="div_add_calc_aantal[3]">
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control add_calc_aantal" name="add_calc_aantal" value="100" onchange="validate_edit(this, 3)">
</div>


<label for="add_calc_totaal_aant">totaal</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_calc_totaal_aant" name="add_calc_totaal_aant" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The input elements seem to have the same name `add_calc_aantal` that can be used to get them:

```js
function calculatie() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName('add_calc_aantal'), i = elems.length, total = 0;
  while (i--) 
    total += elems[i].value | 0;
  document.getElementById('add_calc_totaal_aant').value = total.toFixed( 0 );
}
```

```html
<div onchange=calculatie()>
   <div> <input type=number min=0 step=1 name=add_calc_aantal> </div>
   <div> <input type=number min=0 step=1 name=add_calc_aantal> </div>
   <div> <input type=number min=0 step=1 name=add_calc_aantal> </div>
</div>

Total <input readonly id=add_calc_totaal_aant>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two minor corrections - see comments below:

```
function calculatie() {
    // Absoluut aantal
    var i, totaal = 0;
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control'); // get a handle of the specific inputs - not the divs that surround them
    var l = elems.length;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        totaal += parseFloat(elems[i].value) || 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('add_calc_totaal_aant').value = totaal; // simply assign the value
}
```

In order to run this function you should add an element which will call it, with onclick even: `onclick=calculatie()`, for example:

```
<button name="submit" label="submit" onclick=calculatie()>
```